# How do I format a '<' char in C# code in an xml document?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an XML file that has data in it, but one of the things in it is a section of C# code that is intended for a script for a program.

The problem is I have this code in there for a data table,

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
```

The XML deserialization is getting caught up on the '<' char, for obvious reasons. I already tried escaping it with '\', but that did not work.

Is there a way to have this code in the XML document and have it parse/deserialize correctly? I can change the code to:

```
dt.Rows.Count > i
```

...and it works, but I want to see if there is a way for the other code to work as well.

Comment: Do you have control over the generation of the file? If not, and the file contains these characters, then it's not well formed, and there is no easy way to parse it...

Comment: I will have control over it, but for now I am editing it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&lt;` Less than ( < )

`&gt;` Greater than ( > )

Or you can look into `CDATA`

Answer (score 2):

When I pass code or the like in Xml I use a CData tag

```
 <CodeData>
  <![CDATA[
    <DontParseAsXml>
        Data
    </DontParseAsXml>
   ]]>
 </CodeData>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether or not this will work in your case, but have you tried using an entity (`&lt;`) for your less-than sign? I believe that will get you around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the XML entity `&lt;`. [This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) has a good list of XML entities.